# Can I access data from firebase's real time database on security rules

Tags: firebase

I have a token stored in my /users/UID object, and I want to check if the token provided in the request matches it. How can I do this?

At the moment, I have this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
          "files": {
        ".write": "newData.child(\"token\").val() === \"ZnYKcbTIaN466iQ\"", // 
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The code above returns true, but the token changes periodically. Can I, somehow, access this information in my database?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! To check was quite simple, you just need to use the `data` object

```
 ".write": "newData.child(\"token\").val() === data.child(\"token\").val()"
```